# Not being able to assign a new value to an observable variable with GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm starting to program now and I'm having trouble changing the value of an observable variable, I was wondering if you could help me as it has no syntax errors but still only takes the value assigned to the initializer

**Variable call location**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart';
import 'package:project001_app_waiter/config/custom_colors.dart';
import 'package:project001_app_waiter/pages/base/controller/main_base_controller.dart';
import 'package:project001_app_waiter/pages/kitchen/view/kitchen_screen.dart';
import 'package:project001_app_waiter/pages/requests/controller/requests_controller.dart';
import 'package:project001_app_waiter/pages/table/view/table_tab.dart';
import '../deliver/deliver_tab.dart';

class MainBaseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainBaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainBaseScreen> createState() => _MainBaseScreenState();
}

class _MainBaseScreenState extends State<MainBaseScreen> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final pageController = PageController();
  final requestController = RequestsController();
  final mainBaseController = MainBaseController();

  /*Widget _getNotificationIcon() {
    if (requestController.filterByKitchen(0).isEmpty) {
      return const Icon(Icons.room_service_outlined);
    } else {
      return Badge(
          badgeColor: Colors.red,
          badgeContent: const Text(
            '!',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 10,
            ),
          ),
          child: const Icon(Icons.room_service_outlined));
    }
  }*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: pageController,
        children: [
          const TableTab(),
          const KitchenScreen(),
          const DeliverTab(),
          Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),

      // Barra de navegação
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        // A seleção das 'paginas/icones' 0,1,2,3
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
            pageController.animateToPage(
              index,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
              curve: Curves.ease,
            );
          });
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: CustomColors.customSwatchColor,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(100),
        items: [
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.table_bar_outlined),
            label: 'Mesas',
          ),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.kitchen_outlined),
            label: 'Cozinha',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Obx((){
              return mainBaseController.notification.value;
            }),
            label: 'Pedidos',
          ),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
            label: 'Perfil',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm putting a text as initial return to make it clear that it's not returning from the widget

**Controller**

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../../requests/controller/requests_controller.dart';

class MainBaseController extends GetxController {

  final requestController = RequestsController();

  Rx<Widget> notification =  const Text('Não').obs;

  Widget _getNotificationIcon() {
    if (requestController.filterByKitchen(0).isEmpty) {
      return const Icon(Icons.room_service_outlined);
    } else {
      return Badge(
          badgeColor: Colors.red,
          badgeContent: const Text(
            '!',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 10,
            ),
          ),
          child: const Icon(Icons.room_service_outlined));
    }
  }

  Widget iconNot() => notification.value = _getNotificationIcon();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
  var count = 0.obs;
  increment() => count++;
}
```

try with only value instead of widget

Comment: I've already used it for text and it works!
It doesn't work for widget?

Comment: Till i know ,No. We are alredy using an get builder/obs pettrn to rebuild widget

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your MainBaseScreen can be a Stateless widget, even better, it can be a `GetView<MainBaseController>` so you can access the MainBaseController using `controller` variable.

In the MainBaseController:

```
  RxString notification =  const 'Não'.obs;
```

In the MainBaseScreen:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Obx(() => Text(controller.notification.value),
  label: 'Pedidos',
        ),
```

The particular case from your comment(if I understand it properly):

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: 'Pedidos',
        icon: Obx(() {
          return (controller.isTrue.value) ? Icon(Icons.room_service) : Icon(Icons.room_service_outlined);
        }))
```

Comment: My goal is to return an icon, the text is just to emphasize that the return is wrong. The class cannot be a Stateless as I am still using setState elsewhere, then I will change it to use getx as well

Comment: Obx(
            () => Icon(controller.isDarkMode.value ? Icons.dark_mode : Icons.light_mode),
          ), I use it like this to return an icon. If you provide a little bit more details about which icon / how many icons do you want to return, I can edit my answer.

Comment: Eu quero retornar uma condicional onde se estiver vazia retornara um Icon(Icons.room_service_outlined) e se não estiver vazia retorna Badge(
          badgeColor: Colors.red,
          badgeContent: const Text(
            '!',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 10,
            ),
          ),
          child: const Icon(Icons.room_service_outlined))

Comment: In this case it will be displayed in a BottomNavigationBarItem

Comment: I have edited the answer. I don't know exactly what Badge is, but I think you can achieve what you need using the same structure. isTrue is an observable boolean in your controller (RxBool isTrue = false.obs)

Comment: Got it, I'll try to change